# string formatting an anchor which has to call a javascript function onclick(mvc)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
   goog_snippet_vars = function(){
var w = window;
w.google_conversion_id ="xxxxx";
w.google_conversion_label ="xxxxxx";
w.google_conversion_value ="xxxxxx";
},
goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
goog_snippet_vars();
window.google_conversion_format = '3';
window.google_is_call = true;
var opt = new Object();
opt.onload_callback = function() {
if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {window.location = url;}
}
var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {conv_handler(opt);}
}
</script>
```

I am dumping the above code in to a page(onload) using stringbuilder from server.
and i am using string.format to generate html from server side to the telephone no displayed on the webpage , which on click have to call one of the functions in above script. I used the below code for that

```
string.Format("<a href=\"tel:{0}\" onclick=\"Javascript: goog_report_conversion(tel{0}); return false;\">{0}</a>", PhoneNumber));
```

everything is fine html is applying to the tele no. the issue is on click it is not hitting the function , its simply navigating to new page with url as href value.

so please help me if any work around is there.....thanks...

Comment: Try  
    "goog_report_conversion(tel:{0}); **return false;**"
in your second snippet.

Comment: i tried goog_report_conversion(tel:{0}); return false;    even tried javascript:return goog_report_conversion(tel:{0});   but it never worked...

Comment: mandava, there is a JS error in the goog_snippet_vars() function preventing the "return false;" from being executed: The string XXXXXXXXXXXXXX needs to be put in quotes, like so: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" in both line 2 and 4 of the function's body. The method of appending "return false;" to the onClick handler should work after fixing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue. The main problem is passing the arguments to the script function.
we have to pass some thing like goog_report_conversion(567678899);

For that I had used regex.replace function to remove special characters like below

```
Regex.Replace(sPhone,"[()' '-]","");
```

and passed that in the place of parameter at function call. 
now my generated html looks like below

```
<a onclick="Javascript: goog_report_conversion(2818669180); return false;" href="tel:(281) 866-9180">(281) 866-9180</a>
```

So, Finally I fixed my issue in the above manner. Thanks to all who tried to help me....

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this as your first code snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    goog_snippet_vars = function() {
        var w = window;
        w.google_conversion_id ="xxxxx";
        w.google_conversion_label ="xxxxxx";
        w.google_conversion_value ="xxxxxx";
    };
    goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
        goog_snippet_vars();
        window.google_conversion_format = '3';
        window.google_is_call = true;
        var opt = new Object();
        opt.onload_callback = function() {
            if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {window.location = url;}
        }
        var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
        if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {conv_handler(opt);}
    };
</script>
```

And with something like this for your second snippet:

```
string.Format("<a href=\"tel:{0}\" onclick=\"javascript:goog_report_conversion('tel:{0}'); return false;\">{0}</a>", PhoneNumber));
```

Then, could you post the resulting HTML that your program spits out? (Just the a tag including its attributes should suffice).

**UPDATE**: 
I think your telephone number format leads to errors. You wrote that the result of your string.Format call is

```
<a onclick="Javascript: goog_report_conversion(tel(xxx) xxx-xxxx); return false;" href="tel:(xxx) xxx-xxxx">(xxx) xxx-xxxx</a>
```

with x's representing numbers. There are two problems with this:

1. This is a JS syntax error, the parameter to goog_report_conversion(url) should be a string, something like `goog_report_conversion('tel:xxxxxxxxxx')`. This error also prevents the `return false;` from being executed.
2. The phone number format might be a problem, although I'm not sure about this, because I'm not sure what format `tel:` URLs can have. You should probably get rid of brackets/parentheses and whitespace in the number and adhere to the guides I am linking here: [possibly helpful link 1](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/click-to-call-links-mobile-browsers), [possibly helpful link 2](http://www.marketingtechblog.com/hyperlink-phone-number/)

**UPDATE 2**: [This link](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt) might be useful, it describes the syntax for "tel:" URLs.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: i made all the changes that u mentioned, though is not working           my values are like "xxxxxxxxxxx" and in my string i changed function parameter to tel{0}....................

Comment: mandava, could you update the question with your current code?

Comment: there is nothing in the result to post, it just navigate to a new page which shows the href value in the place of url

Comment: mandava, maybe a misunderstanding - I'd like to see the result of `string.Format(...);` (the generated HTML), not the result of clicking on the link.

Comment: Gruse, sorry about that <a onclick="Javascript: goog_report_conversion(tel(281) 866-9180); return false;" href="tel:(281) 866-9180">(281) 866-9180</a>